# Android menu item visibility change in runtime

Tags: android, exception, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am trying to hide an action bar menu item for a certain period of time while a task is being performed in the background of the running `activity`.

First in the activity's `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method, I retrieve the `MenuItem` instance as a field.

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    // Retrieve and show the contextual settings menu item
    mContextualSettings = menu.findItem(R.id.item_menu_contextual_settings);
    mContextualSettings.setVisible(true);
}
```

Later I use that field to make it invisible and visible again(by using the setVisible method).

I was wondering if this is a good approach or should I somehow use the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to make it visible again? Can I ran into null pointer exceptions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I retrieve the MenuItem instance as a field. [...] I was wondering if this is a good approach or should I somehow use the invalidateOptionsMenu() to make it visible again?

This is not the recommended way to do what you're trying. You're better off using `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` to trigger `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` and a `boolean` field or method to check to then set the visibility of the item directly.

> Can I ran into null pointer exceptions?

In recent versions of Android, it is possible for `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` to be called before the `Menu` has been inflated via `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. So you should always perform a null check on the results of `menu.findItem()`, or otherwise protect against this scenario (perhaps by checking if `menu.getSize() > 0`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you saying that it is possible for the MenuItem field to become null? Also if I understand correctly, you recommend having a boolean field to check the status of the menu item instead?

Comment: I would avoid thinking about this in a way where items "become" null. Instead, think of it like this: every time `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` runs, you will have _some_ menu and menu items, and you will have _some_ program state. Get the menu items you care about with `menu.findItem()`, check that they're not null, and then update them (e.g. `item.setVisible()`) based on the program state. And yes, I would use a boolean... something like `saveVisible = true; supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` followed by `MenuItem save = menu.findItem(R.id.save); if (save != null) { save.setVisible(saveVisible); }`

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing! Using a field to check the state (visible/ivisible) and calling the invalidateOptionMenu to update the menuItem based on that field when it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // instance variable
        public Menu option_Menu

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_container, menu);
    option_Menu = menu;
    option_Menu.findItem(R.id.skip).setVisible(false);      
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    // when task is completed you can show your menu just by calling this method
    public void setMenuVisible(boolean visible, int id) {
    if (option_Menu != null) {
    option_Menu.findItem(id).setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different as you are now keeping the Menu as a field instead of the MenuItem?

Comment: From my above answer you have menu object from which you can call setMenuVisible method with the respective menu item id whom you want to hide or show

Answer (score -1):

Use this way

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_done);      
menuItem.setVisible(true); //visible
menuItem.setVisible(false); //gone
return true;`
```